# Simple Javascript coding for input text to password text

Tags: javascript, html

I have following HTML code. writer input field is text filed. but I want to pretend that one is password field. whenever someone type anything, one key will display as * only, as you know how password field show; additionally the entry at writer input field should be populate in holder value which field is hidden. Can you please write in simple java script coding.

```
 Password: <input type="text" id="writer" value=""/><input type="hidden" id="holder" value=""/>
```

This one show http://www.symplik.com/password.html, whatever we enter, it doesn't look good, it should be all * only when you start typing in it.

Comment: `type=password`- You don't need to populate a hidden one. Just get the value, and you'll get the actual, entered password and not the *s. E.g. you don't need that hidden input.

Comment: ya, i am testing for coding without password... anyway, i got my way :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `<input type="password" id="txtPassord" value=""/>`

Comment: Sorry, thought this is one those newbie questions. Surprised it go so many upvotes! :)